# Dockerize user sessions

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I am looking for some help on how to dockerize user sessions in Linux. What I am looking for is how would I make it so when someone ssh's into an account and does anything, when they exit anything they did isn't saved; it's how I have it set up next time someone else ssh's into it.

It's for a CTF event I've been tasked with setting up and with really no knowledge of most of what I have to do this whole process is a learning experience for me.

A good explanation of how I am hoping to have it set up is explained here: http://overthewire.org/help/sshinfra.html

Comment: So you will same user shared with different people or each would be a different user all together?

Comment: Each user would get their own container when they connect their ssh session

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do that by creating a new docker based shell for the user

**Creating the user**

First we create the user using below command

```
sudo useradd --create-home --shell /usr/local/bin/dockershell tarun 
echo "tarun:tarunpass" | sudo chpasswd
sudo usermod -aG docker tarun
```

**Creating the shell**

Next create a shell file `/usr/local/bin/dockershell`

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -it --rm ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

And then `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dockershell`. Now you can ssh to your vm with the new user

```
$ ssh tarun@vm
tarun@vm's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Sun Oct  1 06:50:06 2017 from 192.168.33.1
Starting shell for tarun
root@79c12f002708:/#
```

This takes me to the docker container and no session changes are saved. If you want to secure it even more, you should be user namespace remapping

https://success.docker.com/KBase/Introduction_to_User_Namespaces_in_Docker_Engine

Comment: Thank you I'll try to test this out today and report back how it works!

Comment: It's sort of up and working now! Your advice worked pretty well.  Now the only issue is the home directory isn't adding when creating the user, and I need to add files to the home directories.

Comment: @Keith, you can do that using a custom image and pass it a environment for folder name that should exists.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure that out.  Thanks for your help, I've been trying to do all I can on an Ubuntu pull that I've been using.  The solution you proposed worked great, all I am going to do is attempt to set up home folders for the user/level.

Answer (score -1):

> when they exit anything they did isn't saved

That is because the  writable layer of a container is discarded when the container stops.

You should make sure your container is run with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) or (better) [a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/): that way, the modification done during the ssh, if done in the right (mounted) path, would persists.

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/images/types-of-mounts-volume.png]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, he is looking on how to setup a SSH to server where user session runs in a docker container and no change from the session is saved

Comment: "no change from the session is saved" which session? the SSH one, or the docker container one? The former should be saved, since it is on the host. The latter needs volume.

Comment: The expectation is that SSH session to the host takes you inside a docker container and not the host. And the docker container changes should not be saved. Which anyways wouldn't be if doesn't map volumes. So the question is more about how to setup a server so that SSH for a user can be sent directly to a docker container shell instead of the host shell

Comment: @TarunLalwani ssh to a container? Why not a simpler docker exec?

Comment: Essentially each "level" or users home folder would be pre-set when they log into it for the CTF level. So they would have to unzip files or perform another task. When they exit that level I want it to go back to how it was pre-set. So I guess their docker session doesn't save I believe is what I am trying to say