# Providing shell access to particular docker container to user which is not added to docker group

Tags: linux, docker, nsenter

My task is provide access to particular docker container without adding user to `docker` group.

What I did

1) Made a `nsenter-based` script which must enter container (let's call it `script1.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} kayako-dashboard)
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid /bin/sh
```

2) Make this script globally available `sudo ln -s /full/path/to/script1.sh /usr/local/bin/some_new_command`

3) Adjusted target ssh key by adding `command="some_new_command"` before `ssh-rsa` in `authorized_keys` file.

But when I log in under target user

`sshpass -p <user_password> ssh <target_user>@<docker_host> "some_new_command"`

I got an error `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

What is wrong and is there any way to fix ?

My kernel version is `4.4.0`, so it supports entering the pid namespace.

nsenter version: `nsenter from util-linux 2.27.1`

P.S. Even if I add `<target_user` to `docker` group and try to execute `some_new_command` I got an error: `nsenter: cannot open /proc/<PID>/ns/ipc: Permission denied`

P.P.S. If I use sudo `some_new_command` are executing fine.

Comment: You have 2 problems here actually. 1st is getting PID of process from docker inspect. This itself requires user to be able to run docker commands. 2nd problem is that you try to run nsenter as non root user to access other user process. It works with sudo because then you run all as root. If you need some unprivileged access I would experiment with https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerAttachWebsocket and create web app that allows access to specific containers.

Comment: Do you want user to just access just this container or host (system)+ this container?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, just container

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508679/dockerize-user-sessions/46509952#46509952